# How to configure horizontal scroll bar for Sitecore SPEAK 2.0 ListControl Component?

Tags: speak

Successfully created a new sitecore speak application with a list control. The list has more than 15 columns and in order to display them all, a horizontal scroll bar is required. By default, the list control component is not showing all the columns, instead it is hiding the columns after the screen size limit is over. Please refer the screenshot. Is there any way to add a horizontal scroll bar[image]

Comment: J.Joseph, this answer any good to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is not possible in Speak 2 based on documentation from Sitecore. It is stated [here](https://doc.sitecore.net/speak/80/components/listcontrol) that ListControl control supports a number of behaviors: EndlessPageScroll, MultiSelectList, and Scrollbar.

Both **EndlessPageScroll** and **Scrollbar** are dependent on height of your ListControl **not** width. See more about Scrollbar [here](https://doc.sitecore.net/speak/80/components/scrollbar) and about EndlessPageScroll [here](https://doc.sitecore.net/speak/80/components/endlesspagescroll).

You have couple of options how to overcome these limitations:

1. You can create [tabcontrol](https://doc.sitecore.net/speak/components/tabcontrol) and tabs and divide current listcontrol into two controls where in first tab you will have 8 columns like now and in second `Action` and `Customer Id` columns similarly to first tab + remaining columns which are currently hidden
2. You can also use [popover](https://doc.sitecore.net/speak/components/popover) and add 'More details' to your 'Actions' which will open this popover with remaining details which are currently hidden.
3. You could also use [frame](https://doc.sitecore.net/speak/components/frame) where you will display your custom page with table with all information. This should be scrollable.

And lots of other options. It depends on what client will be comfortable with.

I would also maybe replace 'Add' and 'Remove' links in 'Actions' column with images which would squeeze width of that column a bit.

More information about listcontrol can be found here:

- https://doc.sitecore.net/speak/80/development/walkthrough_customize_the_listcontrol
- https://doc.sitecore.net/speak/80/components/listcontrol